# Multiprocessing - How to cancel processes with keyboard interrupt?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to spawn two processes to do stuff in while loop until I cancel it with crtl-c which should clear the running flag and end the execution. This works sometimes, but other times it just hangs and i need to manually kill the processes.

```
def func(running_flag: mp.Event, queue: mp.Queue):
   counter = 0
   while running_flag.is_set():
       counter += 1
       msg = "\nCounter:" + str(counter)
       queue.put(msg)


def manage_ctrlC(*args):
   running_flag.clear()


def main():
   signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, manage_ctrlC)
   global running_flag
   processes = []
   queue_y = mp.Queue()
   queue_z = mp.Queue()
   running_flag.set()
   processes.append(mp.Process(target=func,
                            args=(running_flag,queue_y)))
   processes.append(mp.Process(target=func,
                            args=(running_flag,queue_z)))

   try:
       for p in processes:
           p.start()   

   finally:
    
       for p in processes:
           p.join()

       return
```

Comment: You need to declare running_flag as global in manage_ctrlC otherwise it is just a local variable.  As for why it "works" sometimes - possibly crashing with no message

Comment: You should tag your question with the platform you are running on; we need to know. And couldn't you bother to include the import statements and the invocation of `main` to make this a complete [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?